# Solving a non-homogeneous Euler ODE: $ \frac{d}{dx} \left( x^2 f'(x) \right) - 6 f(x) = \frac{2a}{x^2}. $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone solve below equation?

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( x^2 f'(x) \right) - 6 f(x) = \frac{2a}{x^2}.
$$

I can solve homogeneous part:

$$f_g= c_1 e^{-3x}+ c_2 e^{2x}$$

But I can not find the particular solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the product rule, we see that this is a second order nonhomogeneous ODE:
$$x^2f''+2xf'-6f=\frac{2a}{x^2} \tag{1}$$
This is because it can be written in the following form by dividing both sides by $x^2$:
$$f''+p(x)f'+q(x)f=r(x) \tag{2}$$

---

Remember that the ansatz for a Cauchy-Euler equation is $y=x^{\lambda}$, which you seem to have found the roots correctly as $\lambda=-3,2$, but when writing the general solution to the homogeneous part you seem to have used $y=e^{\lambda x}$ instead, which is the well known ansatz for a homogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients. Hence, the homogeneous solution should in fact be:
$$f_h(x)=\frac{c_1}{x^3}+c_2 x^2$$

---

Here, [Variation of Parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) seems like the best method to find the particular solution. The basis solutions are $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$ and $x^2$. Therefore, we compute the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to be:
$$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix} \frac{1}{x^3} & x^2 \\ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) & \frac{d}{dx}(x^2) \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} \frac{1}{x^3} & x^2 \\ -\frac{3}{x^4} & 2x \end{vmatrix}=\frac{5}{x^2}$$
The particular solution will be given by:
$$f_p(x)=\frac{v_1(x)}{x^3}+v_2(x)\cdot x^2 \tag{3}$$
Where:
$$v_1(x)=-\int \frac{r(x)\cdot x^2}{W(x)}~dx=-\int \frac{2a}{5}~dx$$
$$v_2(x)=\int \frac{r(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x^3}}{W(x)}~dx=\int \frac{2a}{5x^5}~dx$$
Here $r(x)$ refers to the one of equation $(2)$, hence $r(x)=\dfrac{2a}{x^4}$. It remains to evaluate the two above integrals, and substitute them into the particular solution on $(3)$.

Comment: y_p=-a(2/(5x^2)+1(10 x^2))

Comment: @SoniaSohi Indeed, and you can simplify that to $f_p=-\frac{a}{2x^2}$. Hence you can now use $f(x)=f_h(x)+f_p(x)$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much